# hyphenation and utf8

Tags: hyphenation, unicode

from [Tex FAQ - hyphenation](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nohyph%20hyphexcept) I see that trying to help Latex in correctly hyphenating words won't work when the utf8 encoding is used. Is there a work around?

Comment: Is 'Use LuaTeX or XeTeX' going to be an acceptable answer?

Comment: The web page you are quoting doesn't contain the word "utf8" and actually doesn't say anything about input encodings. Your claim is wrong.

Comment: @Ulrike: should I add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in my preambule together with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`?

Comment: @Joseph: I am still a pdflatex user but I may switch sometime in the future.

Comment: @pluton: Yes you need T1-encoding.

Comment: @Ulrike: for some reason, I thought `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` was sufficient. I'll put an answer. It may be useful to someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since it may be useful to someone, for specific languages with accents for instance, the \hyphenation command will correctly work only with a T1-encoding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` but won't without.

Comment: @pluton: I don't think this is quite correct. The `\hyphenation` command will work when the font encoding corresponds to what is pre-supposed in the pattern file, and when the hyphenated word uses only accented letters available as single glyphs. Althougth I am not sure what I say is 100% correct, at least the following code shows  that your restriction to T1 is not correct:

Comment: \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[greek]{babel}
    \usepackage{gfsbodoni}
    \usepackage[LGRx,LGR]{fontenc}

    \hyphenation{\'ab-gd-\>ez}

    \def\somestuff{abgdez
      abgdez abgdez abgdez
      abgdez abgdez abgdez}

    \def\somestuffwithaccent{\'abgd\>ez
      \'abgd\>ez \'abgd\>ez \'abgd\>ez
      \'abgd\>ez \'abgd\>ez \'abgd\>ez}

    \begin{document}

    \parbox{2cm}{\somestuff}\hspace{1cm}
    \parbox{2cm}{\somestuffwithaccent}

    \end{document}

Comment: I should have said that my example uses lgrxenc.def available from http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LGR/ furthermore, my latex format is not precompiled with the greek patterns, so babel complains in the log, and perhaps if I am extremely unlucky a more complete set-up would hyphenate by default abgdez like I arbitrarely declared for its version with the two accents.

Comment: all existing hyphenation pattern packages on ctan have been translated into utf-8, and xetex and luatex use those translated tables (note that in those processors, the font is unicode-based).  inputenc/utf-8 input is translated to some font encoding (e.g., t1, or t2a) that deals with the characters, so hyphenation in this case is completely unaffected by the input coding.

Comment: what about `\hyphenation{éb-gd-é}` ?

Comment: @pluton: You need T1-encoding for your (french) words. The LGR-encoding mentioned by jfbu is for greek and not relevant for you.

Comment: @Ulrike: so "my" answer is correct, I guess.